# Can't find variable React - Even though it is not used in file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting a "Can't find variable: React" error in my react native project. But, what baffles me is that I am not at all using `React` in that file, although, I am importing a custom component which uses it though. Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of my problem.

First up `construction.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class UnderConstruction extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{ padding: 75 }}>
                    This page is under construction :(
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default UnderConstruction;
```

Next up, `render.js`:

```
import UnderConstruction from './construction';

export function render() {
    return (
        <UnderConstruction />
    );
}
```

And lastly, `index.ios.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import * as Factory from './render';

class Demo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return Factory.render();
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Demo', () => Demo);
```

---

Running this app will cause the error `Can't find variable: React` on `render.js` line number `5`, which is:

```
<UnderConstruction />
```

I found out the problem can be solved by just adding an `import` statement for `React` on `render.js` like:

```
import React from 'react';
import UnderConstruction from './construction';

...
```

I am curious as to why should I `import` `React` even though I am not using it in `render.js`, hence this question. So, what causes `Can't find variable: React` error in my `render.js` file?

Comment: did you do `npm i --save react` ?

Comment: @Cherniv I created the app using `react-native init Demo` and my `package.json` has both `"react": "^15.3.2",` and `"react-native": "0.33.0",`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use render function you need to import React in your file because react creates your elements. I would suggest you go through your transpiled Javascript file once, you will understand what I mean.

I was myself facing this issue sometime back and when I saw the transpiled JS file and I then I saw how it works.

So in your transpiled file it would be something similar to this:-

```
(0, _reactDom.render)(_react2.default.createElement(_Root2.default, { store: store, history: history }), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: How can I see the transpiled JS files?

Comment: are u using webpack with babel?

Comment: I created the app using `react-native init Demo` and my `package.json` has only `"react": "^15.3.2"`, and `"react-native": "0.33.0",` as dependencies. It seems react ships with [Babel](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html)

Comment: once you compile you will get a bundled output right? I am talking about that outfile js file

Comment: Found out: `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false`. Thanks for the insight :)